# Storing a method as a member variable of a class

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, member

I have this as one of my members of the class 'KeyEvent':

```
private delegate void eventmethod();
```

And the constructor:

```
public KeyEvent(eventmethod D) 
{
    D();
}
```

What I want to do is instead of calling D() there, I want to store that method (D) as a member variable of KeyEvent, so something like:

```
stored_method = D();
```

And then later in another method of KeyEvent, do something like:

```
stored_method();
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You pretty much have the code already. Just create a member field of the right delegate type and save the parameter to it just like you would with any other data type.

```
private eventmethod MySavedEvent;

public void KeyEvent(eventmethod D) {
    // Save the delegate
    MySavedEvent = D;
}

public void CallSavedEvent() {
    if (MySavedEvent != null) {
        MySavedEvent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like:

```
private Action CallBackFunction {get; set;}

public KeyEvent(Action callback) {
   CallBackFunction = callback;
}
```

Which can be instantiated by:

```
new KeyEvent(MyFunction);
```

Where MyFunction is the name of some function in that class

The KeyEvent class can then invoke that function with:

```
CallBackFunction();
```

The Action class also allows strongly typed parameters to be passed in and the Func class can be used for methods that return a result.

Answer (score 2):

the thing that you want is called "first class function" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

C#, since version 3, supports anonymous functions and lambda expressions.

So you can use `Func<A,R>` which represents a function taking an argument of type A and returning a value of type R

from wiki

```
static Func<double, double> MakeDerivative(Func<double, double> f, double deltaX)
  {
    return (x) => (f(x + deltaX) - f(x - deltaX)) / (2 * deltaX);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class KeyEvent
{
  private eventmethod hurr;
  public KeyEvent(eventmethod D)
  {
    hurr = D;
  }
  public void SomeOtherMethod()
  {
    hurr();
  }
}
```

Couple things... PascalCase types/delegates/etc (EventMethod) and camelCase arguments (d, dIsMyMethod).  And reuse what the framework gives you:  `private Action hurr;`