# Is there a way to save a method in a variable then call it later? What if my methods return different types?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

Edit: Thank you for the answers. I am currently working on it!!\

I have 3 methods, S() returns string, D() returns double and B() returns bool.

I also have a variable that decides which method I use.
I want do this:

```
    // I tried Func<object> method; but it says D() and B() don't return object.
    // Is there a way to use Delegate method; ? That gives me an eror saying method group is not type System.Delegate
    var method;

    var choice = "D";

    if(choice=="D")
    {
        method = D;
    }
    else if(choice=="B")
    {
        method = B;
    }
    else if(choice=="S")
    {
        method = S;
    }
    else return;

    DoSomething(method); // call another method using the method as a delegate.

    // or instead of calling another method, I want to do:
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
       SomeArray[i] = method();
    }
```

Is this possible?

I read this post:
[Storing a Method as a Member Variable of a Class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008392/storing-a-method-as-a-member-variable-of-a-class-in-c)
But I need to store methods with different return types...

Comment: I'm interested, why do you want to pass around a method instead of declaring it in a scope that you can access on-demand?

Comment: Actually, the methods I need are static so they can be accessed. It's just I need to choose one to use depending on the value in choice, without doing the if-elseif check on choice every time through a loop.

Comment: You need to actually declare a delegate. This will allow you to essentially simulate function pointers in C# as you'd find them in C or C++.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
Delegate method;

...
if (choice == "D") // Consider using a switch...
{
    method = (Func<double>) D;
}
```

Then `DoSomething` would be declared as just `Delegate`, which isn't terribly nice.

Another alternative would be to wrap the method in a delegate which just performs whatever conversion is required to get the return value as `object`:

```
Func<object> method;


...
if (choice == "D") // Consider using a switch...
{
    method = BuildMethod(D);
}

...

// Wrap an existing delegate in another one
static Func<object> BuildMethod<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    return () => func();
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. You could also constrain BuildMethod to take only a value type as T, since a method that returns a reference type will be assignable to Func<object> already via a covariant method-group-to-delegate conversion.

Comment: @Eric: Except for method returning a nullable value type, which would neither satisfy a `where T : struct` constraint, nor work with generic covariance ;)

Comment: @Jon: Good point. I always forget that nullable types don't satisfy the value type constraint.

Comment: @Eric: I'll confess it wasn't the reason for not including a constraint to start with... but it sounds good after the fact :)

Comment: What about a method with parameters?

Comment: @jbyrd: Just use a delegate type that has the right parameters.

Comment: @JonSkeet that wrapping member smells...scenario of just because you can, does not mean you should ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
Func<object> method;

var choice = "D";

if(choice=="D")
{
    method = () => (object)D;
}
else if(choice=="B")
{
    method = () => (object)B;
}
else if(choice=="S")
{
    method = () => (object)S;
}
else return;

DoSomething(method); // call another method using the method as a delegate.

// or instead of calling another method, I want to do:
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
   SomeArray[i] = method();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private delegate int MyDelegate();
private MyDelegate method;


    var choice = "D";

    if(choice=="D")
    {
        method = D;
    }
    else if(choice=="B")
    {
        method = B;
    }
    else if(choice=="S")
    {
        method = S;
    }
    else return;

    DoSomething(method);
```

Comment: The methods don't return `int`, so this won't compile. Also, why do you declare your own version of `Func<int>`?