# Storing an async function as a variable

Tags: c#, async-await, delegates

I have a question that is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008392/storing-a-method-as-a-member-variable-of-a-class-in-c-sharp) but that differs in that in my case I am dealing with Asynchronous functions.

So as the question says I want to store a method in a variable (to call it later)

In the case of syncrhonous functions

```
private delegate void eventmethod();  //(for a function without arguments and return void)

private eventmethod MySavedEvent;

void D()
{
}

MySavedEvent = D;
MySavedEvent();
```

But what happens if the function is actually

```
Task<returnType> D();
```

How can I define the delegate there?

Comment: Do not be misled. A lot of people misunderstand `async`. It's an *implementation* detail. From the perspective of other code considering calling it, it's just like any other method that returns something rather than nothing (`Task<returnType>` vs `void`). So *any* solution discussing return types from delegates will be relevant here. `async` requires no special consideration.

Comment: someone posted and erased an aswer using `Func`. I wish I could have seen it!

Comment: `private Func<returnType> MySavedEvent;` stores a function

Comment: Func is a delegate (pointer) to a method, that takes zero, one or more input parameters, and returns a value (or reference).

Comment: You don't need to define a delegate like that because Func<T> already exists. You can use it like JohnB said. But in case you need to, it would be something like this: `private delegate Task<ReturnType> eventMethod();`