# How to use a single function to hold several functions with different parameters (for HttpClient)

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, dotnet-httpclient

Similar to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811268/storing-an-async-function-as-a-variable?noredirect=1#comment92540692_52811268) but also related to [this question relating to methods with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695537/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-method-in-a-variable-then-call-it-later-what-if-my-met) I want to do the following:

I have a HttpClient variable as in

```
HttpClient client= new HttpClient();
```

Now, we know that this has different methods, such as `PostAsync` and `DeleteAsycn`. You could notice that the arguments for such functions are different. (for example `PostAsync` has a content that `DeleteAsync` does not have)

I want to have a variable that could hold any of these functions (depending on the case it could be Post or Delete or Get etc)

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: How about wrapping your desired method in a parameterless `Action`? So you can store and invoke them without any further effort.

Comment: @thehennyy Thanks, could you give me an example of this? (I am currently looking how to do this too)

Comment: Have a look at this little example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y8nesB.

Comment: If you just want a method that sends some content but allows you to vary the verb, build around `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpClient.SendAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to apply the following approach (I am writing on the fly the code, I have not tested it, so it maybe prone to errors, please check it on yourself):

```
public class IHttpDelegate {
  void run();
}

public abstract class HttpDelegate : IHttpDelegate {

  public HttpClient httpClient;

  public HttpDelegate(Uri uri) {
    this.httpClient = new HttpClient(uri);
  }

  protected httpClient {
    get {
      return this.httpClient ;
    }
  }
}

public class HttpPostDelegate : HttpDelegate {

  private HttpContect httpContent;

  public HttpPostDelegate (Uri uri) : base(uri) {
    this.httpContent = httpContent;
  }

  public HttpContect httpContent {
    get {
      return this.httpContent;
    }
  }

  public void run() {
    httpClient.PostAync(httpContent);
  }

}

public class HttpDeleteDelegate : HttpDelegate {

  public HttpDeleteDelegate (Uri uri) : base(uri) {
  }

  public void run() {
    httpClient.DeleteAync();
  }

}
```

Then you should defined a delegate based on the **IHttpDelegate** interface.

I hope that maybe helpful!